# Django forms: MultipleChoiceField Error too many values to unpack

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

I want to have a checkbox form in which multiple options can be checked. For this I have:

forms.py

```
class ServiceForm(forms.Form):
services = ServiceList.objects.all().values('service_name')

choice = []
for x in services:
    choice.extend(x.values())

service_id = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=True,
                                       widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=choice)
```

views.py

```
def save_data_into_temp(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    detail_form = ServiceForm(data=request.POST)
    if detail_form.is_valid():

        detail = detail_form.save(commit=False)

        detail.save()
```

but this is giving me an error

```
too many values to unpack
```

traceback:
error at line 58

```
58  {{ service_form }}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what line you getting the error in without a full traceback. If you print `choice` .. what do you get? I would generate `choice` like this:

```
service_choice = tuple(
    [(choice, choice) for choice in 
        ServiceList.objects.values_list('service_name', flat=True)])
```